# How can I have borders on my website?

Tags: html, css

I am extremely new to all this `HTML` and `CSS` stuff so keep in mind that I am a newbie and don't just shout at me for not knowing this. :)

I am currently creating a website for myself in order to learn how to make a website. I had a design in mind when i started: a `864px` light `grey` centered area which dropped a shadow on the `white` bg. I accomplished this by making a thin portion of it in PS and repeating it. When i make divisions a have to make them exactly `864px` wide but that causes problems in small devices. Is there a way to make everything bound to those lines?

PS: My English is bad, sorry.
Photo of it, in case I couldn't explain it:
By `border` I tried to mean those shadows.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnMl1.jpg

Comment: for small devices means are you asking about mobile,ipad,iphone etc then you have to check the screen size and device type which you can do by using javascript and server side code for changing the layout based upon the current device..

Comment: dont use a css for that. create 2 png's and repeat-y for them

Comment: @Royi: Why not use CSS? Box-shadow is well supported in most mobile browsers, as well as in most recent desktop browsers.

Comment: @reinder I agree. (in my sites i created it with png)/any way i agree

Answer (score 6):

You could for example use CSS instead of images.

You'll probably get something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <!--864px wide-->
    </div>
</div>

.container
{
    width: 864px;
    margin: 0 auto; /*align in center*/
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #888;
}
```

box-shadow for the shadow, this means: 0 from the left and 0 from the top so a centered shadow, blurred by 5px and color is #888, this may also be a rgba color

Comment: Thanks it worked but now the top of the wrapper isn't touching the top of the page. There is a slight shadow there too. How can I make it touch the browser?

Comment: I would recommend to use some sort of CSS reset. The most simple solution would be: html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:-

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; // you can change it to whatever you want.
```

For adding shadow left and right use this:-

```
<style> 
div {margin: 20px; width: 400px; height: 400px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 2px  #222,  -4px 0 2px #222;   
-moz-box-shadow: 4px 0 2px #222,  -4px 0 2px #222;   
box-shadow: 4px 0 2px #222,  -4px 0 2px #222; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: this wont show him the left ones. `0px 0px 5px #888888;` will